# Datatables cannot read property 'fnGetData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables in my project and everything works great now. But I am getting below warning error in my browser console and I haven't found any clues about why this is coming. But it is not stopping any functionalities.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnGetData' of undefined
```

This is error is just coming after the table draw.

Below are parameter that I am using for my datatable. So you can get some idea on this warning error.

```
var initParams = {
        "bDestroy": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "bSortClasses": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 15, 30, 50, 100, -1], [10, 15, 30, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "sAjaxSource": defaultReq,
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
               "dataType": 'json',
               "type": "GET",
               "url": sSource,
               "data": aoData,
               "success": fnCallback,
               "error": function (e) {
                   console.log(e.message);
               }
           });
        },
        "aoColumns": cols,
        "aoColumnDefs": colDef
    };
```

I am triggering an ajax (sAjaxSource) request to get table data.

Comment: looking your code i couldn't find any problem, can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 5):

Your initialization code is correct. I suspect you're using newer DataTables 1.10.x library (by presence of `autoWidth` option).

Error `Cannot read property 'fnGetData' of undefined` can occur when you're trying to call older version (1.9.x) method `fnGetData()` on API instance of newer 1.10.x version of DataTables, for example:

```
var data = $('#example').DataTables().fnGetData();
```

Correct way to call `fnGetData()` in both 1.9.x and 1.10.x versions is

```
var data = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetData();
```

See [DataTables 1.9 to 1.10 migration reference](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use **rows().nodes()** instead of fnGetData().

Like this,

```
var data = $('#example').DataTables().rows().nodes();
```